# R read_delim recognizing pipe delimiter inconsistently

Tags: r, import

I have run into some problems while importing a pipe delimited file. The file consistently delimits but something is getting in the way of R reading some of the delimiters while parsing. R reads in 10 columns when there should be 11, even though the appropriate number of pipes are in place.

A very small sample of the data can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ek6-H5EWKCaPfDTfB2muqYBjJz1fM3pf/view

```
dat <- read_delim("~/Desktop/foo.txt", delim = "|", col.names = TRUE)
```

I've tried playing around with how R treats the quotes... `quote = "/""` did nothing to help and ignoring the quotes with `quote = ""` made an even bigger mess of the import.

Any thoughts on how to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you attach a text file with a subset of the data you are trying to load? Your problem is not possible to reproduce from the doc you linked. Thanks.

Comment: Don't post Google drive links if you can avoid it. Copy and paste of 5 or 6 lines of text that can reproduce the problem will be fine. No way I'm ever clicking on a random link from a new forum user.

Comment: Also try `read.delim` from base R instead of `readr`'s `read_delim` and see if you get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to use fread() in data.table package as below.

```
library(data.table)
FOO3<-fread("~/Downloads/foo.txt",sep = "|",fill = T)
```

Below is the import dataset I got.

[image]